# How to find a child element with a specific value and delete it's immediate parent node?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to find an element `<strong class="name">Priority:</strong>` . If that exists I need to delete the parent element of it i.e `<div class="wrap">`
I know there are other elements also exists in `<li class="item">`. e.g `<strong class="name">Type:</strong>`. but that shouldn't touched.

```
<li class="item">
    <div class="wrap">
        <strong class="name">Type:</strong>
        <span id="type-val" class="value">
             <img alt="Task" height="16" src="task.png" title="" width="16"> Task
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="item">
        <div class="wrap">
            <strong class="name">Priority:</strong>
            <span id="priority-val" class="value editable-field inactive" title="Click to edit">
                   <img alt="2. Critical" height="16" src="/critical.png" title="2"> 2. Critical
            <span class="overlay-icon aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-edit"></span></span>
        </div>
</li>
```

I tried below code, but it didn't help.

```
$("li.item").find("strong.name").each(function(){
if (this[value="Priority:"]) {
    this.parent.remove()
}
});
```

Comment: Should `<strong class="name">High Priority:</strong>` parent be deleted as well? Does `<strong>` parent always has class `.wrap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to combine [`:has`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) with [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). For example:

```
$('li.item .wrap:has(strong.name:contains("Priority:"))').remove();
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8o7dxy23/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()` and `closest('li')` to delete parent `li`.

```
$("li.item strong.name").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().indexOf('Priority:') > -1;
}).closest('li').remove();
  //to remove <div class="wrap"> use parent() instead of closest(..)
```

or use `:contains()`

```
$("li.item strong.name:contains(Priority:)").closest('li').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('.name').each(function(){
     $val = $(this).text();

     if ($val == "Priority:") {
       $(this).parent().remove();
     };
  });
```